# What "given a foliation $f:L \to M$ " means?

Tags: differential-topology, foliations

I'm reading this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039616301516?via%3Dihub). And on page $4$ the author writes the following paragraph:

[image]

I am not sure about what the phrase "given a foliation $f:L\to M$" means. A foliation is an atlas, so it is awkward to say that a function is a foliation. At first sight, I thought that the phrase "$f:L\to M$" was simply an inaccurate way to say "the foliation induced by the submersion $f$". However as we can see over the underlined line there is the phrase "so that $f$ must be a $\mathcal{C}^r$-immersion", then my assumption is wrong.

Can anyone help me to understand what "given $f:L\to M$" actually means?.

Just for the records the definition of foliation that I use is the same that we can find on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but is it possible that to say that $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a foliation is to say that the leaves of the fioliation under question are the fibers of $f$, that is, the elements of $$\{f^{-1}(b):b \in B\}$$

? This seems possible.

[According to wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation#Submersions)

> If $M^n → N^q (q \leq n)$ is a submersion of manifolds, it follows from the inverse function theorem that the connected components of the fibers of the submersion define a codimension $q$ foliation of $M$. Fiber bundles are an example of this type.

So it seems that foliations can be viewed special cases of surjective mappings between manifolds, and/or as generalizations of submersions.

Comment: Once $f$ is an immersion, according to the text, then $\text{dim}(L) \leq \text{dim}(M)$, therefore I am not  convinced by your answer.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto, but isn't that how foliations (of $L$) work? The leaves need to have strictly smaller dimension than the ambient space. Given a surjective map $f : L \rightarrow M$, we expect that the fibers $f^{-1}(m)$ will have dimension $\mathrm{dim}(L)-\mathrm{dim}(M)$. But this number obviously must be greater than or equal to $0$, hence $\mathrm{dim}(L)-\mathrm{dim}(M) \geq 0$ from which your inequality follows.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto, oh, I see. The inequality is going the wrong way. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto, maybe that just tells us that foliations are almost never immersions?